# Need the date from a table and populate a datetimepicker with the date from the table

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried so many different ways to do this and none of them seem to work. I just need the dates from a table to populate a datetimepicker. Here is my code below. When the cmbSitePSI3 index is changed I have a ton of cmb and txt boxes that get auto-populated including two datetimnepickers. I have tried parse, parseexact, etc...this is just the last part where I left off.

I am getting System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

```
 private void CmbSitePSI3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView rv1 = cmbSitePSI3.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        if (rv1 != null)
        {
            dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse(rv1.Row[31].ToString());
            //dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(rv1.Row[32].ToString());
            cmbDayNight.Text = rv1[35].ToString(); //takes data from the server data table that matches the column header and writes to a string value to the txtbox
            txtCombined.Text = rv1[36].ToString();
            cmbSiteType.Text = rv1[37].ToString();
            
        }
        else
        {
            ClearSite();
        }
```

I have successfully converted a string date to a datetimepicker beofre but not sure why this is not working, before I used this code:

```
 private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {            
        DataGridViewRow dgvRow = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        txtProjID2.Text = dgvRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        cmbCore.Text = dgvRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        cmbRole.Text = dgvRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        cmbName.Text = dgvRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        cmbRate.Text = dgvRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        cmbTravel.Text = dgvRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dgvRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
        txtComments.Text = dgvRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Probably best off using either a cast `(DateTime)` or `DateTime.Parse` rather than `Convert.ToDateTime`

Answer (score 0):

I had the column number wrong and I removed **Row** and it is working.

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(rv1[32].ToString());
dateTimePicker2.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(rv1[33].ToString());
```